# Angular ngModel and event doesn't change

Tags: angular

**When I input some value. The  doesn't change,
  I hope the carData can change by the keyup event.
  I have many input tags, so i hope i can only write one method to call it **

**ts:**

```
  carData:string;
  deleteInputStream(data) {
  data = data.replace(/[^0-9.]/g, '');
  return data;}
```

**html**

```
<input [(ngModel)]="carData"(keyup)="deleteInputStream(carData)"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a patch , but will work for all you dynamic values

**Template side :**

```
deleteInputStream(data) {
    return data.target.value = data.target.value.replace(/[^0-9.]/g, '');
}
```

**Component side :**

```
<input [ngModel]="carData" name="carData" (input)="carData = deleteInputStream($event)"/>
{{carData}} <br/>
```

**[WORKING DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-input-keyup)**

Comment: I have many data . eg: this.carData2 . this.carData3 ...... I wanna  write a common method